# sprockets failed to prepare assets for nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, asset-pipeline, sprockets, puma

I want to let `nginx` serve the static files for cache task.

But I got `No such file or directory` from nginx error log.

It seems the css files included in `root-c452663d516929cd4bb4c1cd521971eb.css` could not be served.

How could I fix the bug

## production.rb

```
  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  #config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
  config.serve_static_files = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true
```

## http://localhost/assets/kode/css/root-c452663d516929cd4bb4c1cd521971eb.css

```
/* Summernote */
@import url('plugin/summernote/summernote.css');
@import url('plugin/summernote/summernote-bs3.css');

/* Sweet Alert */
@import url('plugin/sweet-alert/sweet-alert.css');

/* Data Tables */
@import url('plugin/datatables/datatables.css');

/* Chartist */
@import url('plugin/chartist/chartist.min.css');

/* Rickshaw */
@import url('plugin/rickshaw/rickshaw.css');
@import url('plugin/rickshaw/detail.css');
@import url('plugin/rickshaw/graph.css');
@import url('plugin/rickshaw/legend.css');
```

## nginx setting

```
location / {
try_files $uri @sample;
gzip_static       on;
expires           max;
add_header        Cache-Control public;
}

location @sample {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://sample;
}
  location ~* ^/assets/ {
      # Per RFC2616 - 1 year maximum expiry
      expires 1y;
      add_header Cache-Control public;

      # Some browsers still send conditional-GET requests if there's a
      # Last-Modified header or an ETag header even if they haven't
      # reached the expiry date sent in the Expires header.
      add_header Last-Modified "";
      add_header ETag "";
      break;
    }
```

## Error log

```
2015/07/22 17:27:02 [error] 9891#0: *9 open() "/var/public/assets/kode/css/plugin/date-range-picker/daterangepicker-bs3.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 118.166.217.131, server: www.localhost, request: "GET /assets/kode/css/plugin/date-range-picker/daterangepicker-bs3.css HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/assets/kode/css/root-c452663d516929cd4bb4c1cd521971eb.css"
2015/07/22 17:27:02 [error] 9891#0: *10 open() "/var/public/assets/kode/css/plugin/rickshaw/legend.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 118.166.217.131, server: www.localhost, request: "GET /assets/kode/css/plugin/rickshaw/legend.css HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/assets/kode/css/root-c452663d516929cd4bb4c1cd521971eb.css"
2015/07/22 17:27:02 [error] 9891#0: *11 open() "/var/public/assets/kode/css/plugin/rickshaw/detail.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 118.166.217.131, server: www.localhost, request: "GET /assets/kode/css/plugin/rickshaw/detail.css HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/assets/kode/css/root-c452663d516929cd4bb4c1cd521971eb.css"
2015/07/22 17:27:02 [error] 9891#0: *5 open() "/var/public/assets/kode/css/plugin/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 118.166.217.131, server: www.localhost, request: "GET /assets/kode/css/plugin/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/assets/kode/css/root-c452663d516929cd4bb4c1cd521971eb.css"
```

## puma.config

```
app_path = File.expand_path('../', File.dirname(__FILE__))
pidfile "#{app_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
bind "unix:///tmp/puma.lazyair.sock"
stdout_redirect "#{app_path}/log/puma.stdout.log", "#{app_path}/log/puma.stderr.log", true
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 6)
threads_count = Integer(6)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT'] ||  3457

# Default to production
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "production"
environment rails_env

on_worker_boot do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
activate_control_app
```